# SQL Get current day in numeric format

Tags: sql, date

I am attempting to grab the current day in the format 01 - 07 or 1 - 7.

This is the query I am using `SELECT id FROM tbl_date WHERE weekday = WEEKDAY(NOW)` but I seem to get false in return so am not sure I am using the function correctly. The table column `weekday` contains a number 1 - 7 where 1 is sunday/monday.

Any ideas?

Comment: What RDMBS are you using?

Comment: For any future questions, please be more specific about the error you are getting and please be more specific about the type of database.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid misstake by me. The correct way would be `weekday = WEEKDAY(NOW())` since `NOW()` itself is a function.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL can use `DATEPART(dw, GETDATE())`, MySQL can use `DAYOFWEEK()`